# LC to LC Patch Panel Connections

Tags: network

I'm just going to install an 8 Core OM3 Fibre between two patch bays (200M).
Is it standard practice to connect Fibre 1 to LC1/1 - Fibre 2 to LC1/2
- Fibre 3 to LC2/1 - Fibre 4 to LC2/2 etc. etc.
Where LC1/1 is top or left and LC1/2 is bottom or right depending if the terminals are mounted vertically or horizontally.
As I understand you don't cross fibres you do that on the patch cords?
Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You always connect fibers vertically in a patch panel, so that fiber 1 and 2 are set together as a pair.

[image]

Here pair 1 consists of fiber 1 and 2 and so forth.

To make sure you have them crossed in relation to the patch cable, the LC connector houses are turned away from each other in both ends. For instance, at the primary wiring closet, you turn the connector right and in the secondary you turn it left. That way the connection will be established without the need to break the duplex cables, when they come gathered.

Crossover example:

[image]

The left picture is the primary wiring closet.

The right picture is the secondary wiring closet.

This way you are 100% that all connectors are crossed.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to make up Panel 1 with connectors to facing left and on Panel 2 connectors facing right. If I shine a laser down No: 1 fibre (as in your picture) at Panel 1 you will see it on the bottom of the right facing connector at Panel 2 - is this correct? Or is the fibre reversed to come out of the upper slot?

Comment: @AndrewT yes sir, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand you don't cross fibres you do that on the patch cords?

That would actually be non-standard. You do cross the fibers. According to the *ANSI/TIA/EIA 568, Commercial Building Telecommunications Cabling Standard*, you are to connect the fibers as a crossover:

> Each cabling segment shall be installed such that odd numbered fibers
>   are Position A at one end and Position B at the other end while the
>   even numbered fibers are Position B at one end and Position A at the
>   other end.

-and-

> The 568SC implementation shall be achieved by using consecutive fiber 
>   numbering (i.e., 1,2,3,4...) on both ends of an optical fiber link,
>   but the 568SC adapters shall be installed in opposite manners on each
>   end (i.e., A-B, A-B... on one end and B-A, B-A... on the other).

-and-

> For other duplex connector styles, polarity may be achieved either by
>   using the above method for the 568SC or by using reverse-pair
>   positioning. Reverse-pair positioning is achieved by installing fibers
>   in consecutive fiber numbering (i.e., 1,2,3,4....) on one end of an
>   optical fiber link and reverse-pair numbering (i.e., 2,1,4,3....) on
>   the other end of the optical fiber link.

If you do that, and your patch cables are all the same (straight-through or crossover), you will end up with an odd number of crossovers, so the connection between devices will properly be crossed over.